# Can't make ProgressBar use material design style

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design, android-theme, android-styles

I'm transitioning an app from Holo style to Material design, and am stuck with a `ProgressBar` widget that won't show up as it is supposed to.

It's supposed to be flat like (and that's what AndroidStudio's preview gives me):

[image: flat progress bar]

But when on the emulator (running Android 7.1.1), I only get the version with an arrow tip (also, it's not being animated)

[image: arrow-pointed progress bar]

I've already tried removing every single bit of customization on top of the base AppTheme, which inherits from Material:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light"></style>
```

The ProgressBar is declared without any styling whatsoever, plain:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_activity_login_progressbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true" />
```

I'm at a loss here, already removed everything on the project that could reference styling, but this still happens. Already cleaned/rebuilt the project many times. What am I missing? How can I make that progress bar look like the flat one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem of the emulator. Sometimes emulator does not give us the proper result.

If you run it on a device then you will get to see the difference and it also depends on a device. If any device's OS is customized then the progress bar may look different.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Just ran it on my device and it shows the expected output. Is there any way to make the emulator match more closely?

Comment: @DélissonJunio Are you using Genymotion or Android Studio's emulator?

Comment: Android Studio's emulator

Comment: Use Genymotion. This is better than Android Studio's emulator.